# What is or what "fast-ramping batteries" means at this context?

Tags: power, batteries, system, storage

I'm trying to do a economics report of Battery Storage, but I'm from Brazil, so I have to find especific words used in portuguese to describe certain things in electrical setor. I find this term "fast-ramping" and have no idea what this means. I think if someone explain the means and a context for this expression so I can find an equivalent word in my language.

**Context**:

"Balancing grid supply and demand.  Batteries can help balance electricity supply and demand on multiple time scales (by the second, minute, or hour).  Fast-ramping batteries are particularly well suited to provide ancillary grid services such as frequency regulation, which helps maintain the grid’s electric frequency on a second-to-second basis."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ramping" up or down is a utility grid term for how quickly a generator can add power to the grid, or reduce its output when demand reduces.

Steam generating plant cannot ramp fast - it can take hours, up to days for some nuclear plants to reach full power again after a shutdown. Other plant - especially hydro - can ramp up as fast as you can turn a tap.

There's nothing stopping battery storage reaching full power instantly, which makes it "fast ramping" -valuable for stabilising a grid in the presence of variable load - or sudden [changes in generating capacity if a plant shuts down](https://reneweconomy.com.au/tesla-big-battery-outsmarts-lumbering-coal-units-after-loy-yang-trips-70003/).

This allows better - [and cheaper](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/feb/06/how-teslas-big-battery-is-bringing-australias-gas-cartel-to-heel) - frequency control.